# Disable tag completion in (grunt-contrib-)htmlmin

Tags: gruntjs, grunt-contrib-htmlmin

I have a rather typical PHP project in which the header/footer parts of pages are reused and therefore placed in separate files that I simply `require` from the main file.

This means, however, that my `_header.php`-file ends in an open `<article>` tag (which is then "closed" at the beginning of `_footer.php`).

The problem is that `htmlmin` interprets this as an error on my part and adds closing `article`, `body` and `html` tags in `_header.php`. How do I 'disable' that? I've read through the GitHub pages of [grunt-contrib-htmlmin](https://github.com/gruntjs/grunt-contrib-htmlmin) *and* [html-minifier](https://github.com/kangax/html-minifier) without much luck.

**My Task Config**

```
htmlmin: {                                      
    dist: {                                     
        options: {   
            minifyJS: true,
            removeComments: true,
            collapseWhitespace: true
        },
        files: {                                
            'staging/index.php': 'index.php',
            'staging/support/index.php': 'support/index.php',
            'staging/inc/_header.php': 'inc/_header.php',
            'staging/inc/_footer.php': 'inc/_footer.php'
        }
    }
}
```

*Bonus brownie points if you can also tell my why `minifyJS: true` seems to be ignored*

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I searched for a solution, I looked at the documentation, I read several blog posts and I found out that at this time what you are asking is **impossible**.

Moreover someone asked a similar question on GitHub, [Support for html fragments](https://github.com/kangax/html-minifier/issues/118), but it was closed with the answer:

> Hm, I don't think there's much we can do about this, since minifier really needs to be context aware and can't understand what to do with arbitrary, partial chunk of html.

So this is not possible and this is (probably) **not going to be implemented in the future**.

You **can't block that process** (with grunt-contrib-htmlmin) because their intent is to specifically prevent users from leaving "uncorrect code".

I did not find any other equivalent grunt-plugin that gives you that possibility.

In the end I think you have only two "solutions" left:

1)Not minifying your php fragments;

2)**Divide your code into more parts, minify only the one without unclosed tags, and reunite them all using [grunt-include-replace](https://github.com/alanshaw/grunt-include-replace)**, or a similar plugin, in a new php file.

Comment: Really thorough. Thanks for going the extra mile on answering my question!

Answer (score 1):

One solution, I know not ideal, would be to use the ignore comments by wrapping your markup in:

```
<!-- htmlmin:ignore -->
```

https://github.com/kangax/html-minifier#ignoring-chunks-of-markup

Or perhaps you could use a different tool like HTML Clean:

https://www.npmjs.com/package/grunt-htmlclean

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue and fixed it with a combination of `htmlmin:ignore` and `includeAutoGeneratedTags`

grunt.js

```js
htmlmin: {
    dist: {
      options: {
          removeComments: true,
          includeAutoGeneratedTags: false,
          collapseWhitespace: true,
          conservativeCollapse: true, 
   },
   files: [
        { src: ['<%= meta.deployPath %>/includes/footer.php'], dest: '<%= meta.deployPath %>/includes/footer.php', nonull: true},
      ]
     }
    },
```

footer.php

```html
<!-- htmlmin:ignore --></div><!-- htmlmin:ignore -->
<footer id="page-footer" role="contentinfo">
...
```